# what is difference between creating & running the workflow in client and server?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

am new to informatica .
can anyone tell me what is difference between creating & running the workflow in client and server.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The workflows are always executed on the server that runs the Integration Service.

The PowerCenter client tools (Designer, Workflow Manager, Workflow Monitor, Repository Manager) cannot run workflows by themselves. They can only be used to develop mappings, sessions and workflows. Workflow Manager and Workflow Monitor can be used to start and workflow execution.

Comment: can you also explain me what is workflow log directory and I know that its default value is $PMWorkflowLogDir\ and also wt does that $ stands for.

Comment: Workflow log directory is pretty self explanatory, I think. It is the directory where workflow logs are stored! The $ means it is a workflow variable. You can override it's value using a parameter file.

Answer (score 0):

$XXXXXX means that $XXXXXX is a variable. System variables usually begin with $PMXXXX

To change the variable value:

1. Enter in the Administration Console.
2. Select the integration service that you are using to run the
   workflows.
3. Processes tab and click on EDIT
4. Select the Processes tab.
5. Click Edit

Then you can edit the values of the system variables